# How to merge list to become string without adding any character in python?

Tags: python, string, list, merge

I found that I can join them with '-'.join(name) but I dont want to add any character. Lets say I have 
     `['stanje1', '|', 'st6', ',' 'stanje2', '|', '#']`
and I want to be like this

```
stanje1|st6,stanje2|#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can just do it as:

`''.join(name)`

```
>>> name = ['stanje1', '|', 'st6', ',' 'stanje2', '|', '#']
>>> print ''.join(name)
stanje1|st6,stanje2|#
```

This will join the string with no intermediate string.

#### Examples

```
>>> s = ['Hello', 'World']
>>> print ''.join(s)
HelloWorld

>>> print '-'.join(s)
Hello-World
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ommit the -:

```
''.join(name)
```