# How to Convert list into string and concatenate it with another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a list **L=[1,2,3]**  into string **"123"** and then concatenate that string with another string **"45"**

Comment: `final_string = ''.join(map(str, L)) + "45"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge list to become string without adding any character in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104201/how-to-merge-list-to-become-string-without-adding-any-character-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension to `cast` and then `join`, like this:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
output = ''.join(str(i) for i in L) + "45"
```

Or you could do it in a different way like so:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
output = ("{}" * len(L)).format(*L) + "45"
```

Comment: You don't have to build the list inside `join`. just `output = ''.join(str(i) for i in L) + "45"` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

To concat a python list into a string, you could use `''.join(your_list)`, on the **prerequisite** that all your items within the list are of type `str`.

For your question, since items within your list `L` are integers, you would have to convert them into strings before you can join them together.

To concat 2 strings together, you can choose to use string formatting, or to concat 2 strings together with a plus sign.

Putting everything together, you would get the following code snippet:

```
list_to_str = ''.join(map(str,L))

# concat using string formatting
output = "{}{}".format(list_to_str, "45")

# concat using addition of strings
output = list_to_str + "45"
```

Answer (score 0):

CODE:

```
L = [1,2,3]
a = ''
b = '45'
c = ''
#convert a list L=[1,2,3] into string "123"
for l in L:
    a += str(l)
#result '123'
print(a)

#concatenate that string with another string "45"
c = a+b
#result '12345'
print(c)
```

This code use str_function to convert elements into string.